# Is it a bad idea to use a future inside a singleton class?

Tags: singleton, task, future, java-threads

I am currently interning in a company and just starting to get into their code. I noticed that they have tasks that use singleton classes, but inside the singleton class there is a future object that is used to fetch thread dumps.

The code goes something like this:

```
singltonclass{
private ExecutorService x= Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
getInstance method(){}
methodThatFetchsThreadDumps(){
future is used here;
}
}
```

Is it a good idea to use a future inside a singleton? What happens if the task using this singleton runs twice and overlaps? Wouldn’t using the singleton multiple times cause the future to give unexpected behavior?

Comment: i think this question belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @a4arpan please read our help pages before you suggest that a question would belong to code review. In its current state (example code) it would be closed as **off topic** in a heartbeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't necessarily a bad thing. The Future will make sure that the objects returned will be visible across threads. The thread pool is fixed at size of 1, so if there are concurrent requests the second one blocks until the only worker thread becomes available, by which time it has handed off its results from the previous task. No overlap should be occurring.

Comment: but it will block the whole execution until the thread is finished which defeats the whole purpose of threading? right???

Comment: @halaesseili: the future only blocks if something is waiting on the result. with a better example the issues would be a lot clearer.